Installer for an older version of Postman for MacOS Intel
The latest version of Postman requires an account. Seems like Postman has retired the links to download the older versions. Can anyone please share the installer for an older version (e.g. 10.13.6) that does not require log-in? (Installer for Mac Intel)

You can use this link :
Postman v10.13.6 x64 + v10.5.2 x86

password please
